# Problems passing Variables Get Set

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I am trying to get my head around get and set calling and storing variables from one class to another.

its a windows form with 2 buttons and 2 textboxes.

Class Utility is to do all the backend calculations and store the variables ActiveUserId and ActiveUserName. For now all I want to do is store the value of the two textboxes and be able to get them after.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  class Utility
  {     
    public int ActiveUserID;
    public string ActiveUserName;     

    public int _ActiveUserID
    {
      get { return ActiveUserID;}
      set { ActiveUserID = value; }
    }

    public string _ActiveUserName
    {
      get { return ActiveUserName; }
      set { ActiveUserName = value; }
    }

    public void StoreActiveUser(int currentUserID, string currentUserName)
    {    
      ActiveUserID = currentUserID;
      ActiveUserName = currentUserName;
    }

    public int GetActiveUser()
    {
      return ActiveUserID;
    }
  }
}
```

And the other class is

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Utility tool1 = new Utility();
      tool1.StoreActiveUser(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text);
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("the values are :{0}  {1}", tool1.ActiveUserID.ToString(), tool1._ActiveUserName));           
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Utility tool1 = new Utility();
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("the values are :{0}  {1}",tool1.ActiveUserID.ToString(),tool1._ActiveUserName));
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format(tool1.GetActiveUser().ToString()));
    }
  }
}
```

I enter some values in the textboxes and press button1  and the message display's the values correctly.

When I press button 2  I should get the values of ActiveUserID and ActiveUserName from utility class displayd in the message box, all i get is "0"

then i added a function that returns the activeUserID but that returns 0;

Am i not storing permanently the value of ActiveUserID in button1_Click?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The tool1 variable in button1_Click is not related to the tool1 variable in button2_Click (notice you initialize a new instance with the "new" keyword). You'll either want a global Utility variable, a static Utility class, or the variables in question should be static

Comment: Thanks Jake i mate a global utility variable, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite an answer to your question but your Utility class could be improved as well. The fields should be private and start with an underscore (by convention) and the properties should be public:

```
  class Utility
  {     
    private int _activeUserID;
    private string _activeUserName;     

    public int ActiveUserID
    {
      get { return _activeUserID;}
      set { _activeUserID = value; }
    }

    public string ActiveUserName
    {
      get { return _activeUserName; }
      set { _activeUserName = value; }
    }

    // You don't need this method, you can store id and username like this:
    // tool1.ActiveUserID = currentUserID;
    // tool1.ActiveUserName = currentUserName;
    public void StoreActiveUser(int currentUserID, string currentUserName)
    {    
      ActiveUserID = currentUserID;
      ActiveUserName = currentUserName;
    }

    // no need for this method either, you can use this:
    // int id = tool1.ActiveUserID;
    public int GetActiveUser()
    {
      return ActiveUserID;
    }
  }
```

The next step could be to convert the properties to automatic properties:

```
  class Utility
  {     
    public int ActiveUserID { get; set; }
    public string ActiveUserName { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new object in the second button, try this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Utility tool1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tool1 =  new Utility();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tool1.StoreActiveUser(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("the values are :{0}  {1}", tool1.ActiveUserID.ToString(), tool1._ActiveUserName));

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("the values are :{0}  {1}", tool1.ActiveUserID.ToString(), tool1._ActiveUserName));
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format(tool1.GetActiveUser().ToString()));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They may both have the same name (tool1) but they are two completely separate instance of the Utility class. So the data stored in the tool1 instance in button1_Click is not the same in the tool1 instance in button2_Click.

What you need to do is change the scope of tool1 to make it global to both button1_Click and button2_Click. So something like this:

```
Utility tool1 = new Utility();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        tool1.StoreActiveUser(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("the values are :{0}  {1}", tool1.ActiveUserID.ToString(), tool1._ActiveUserName));

    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("the values are :{0}  {1}",tool1.ActiveUserID.ToString(),tool1._ActiveUserName));
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format(tool1.GetActiveUser().ToString()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `Utility` object each time. You should either:

1. Create a single `Utility` object in the `Form()` constructor, and save it as a field:

   ```
   private Utility Tool { get; set; }
   public Form() {
       InitializeComponent();
       Tool = new Utility();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       Tool.StoreActiveUser(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text);
       // ...
   ```
2. Make `Utility` a static class, and refer to `Utility.StoreActiveUser` instead of creating any instances at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
Utility tool1 = new Utility();
```

Your issue here is [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29). Each time you're calling that line of code you're creating a new local variable. You'll need to instantiate a single instance as a class member.